# How do I get a graph of build times in TeamCity?

Tags: continuous-integration, build-automation, teamcity

I want to keep track of our build times for different agents in TeamCity. How do I go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Errr ... it's on the Statistics tab in TeamCity. :)